# Import SharePoint 2007 Site Template into SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

We are moving from **SharePoint 2007** to **SharePoint 2010**.

I saved a site in SharePoint 2007 as a Site Template (SiteName.stp) and I brought it into SharePoint 2010 under "*Site Settings - Galleries - Solutions*" - Noticed that is where the templates get saved in 2010.

But when I upload it there I cant change the Status to "Activate"....

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found here:

Templates created in SharePoint 2007 are not directly usable in SharePoint 2010.  In SharePoint 2007 templates are stored as .STP files, in SharePoint 2010 site templates are stored as .WSP files.  They are different formats and incompatible with each other.

The only possiblilty would be to create a site with it in a SharePoint 2007 environment and then upgrade that environment to SharePoint 2010.  After the upgrade you may be able to create a new template in SharePoint 2010.

[MSDN: Import Template in Share Point 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/dba58b59-c4aa-4a06-aff8-060b929c4650)

Comment: @Mike: They'd pasted the link in twice: fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this problem a long time ago by creating my own sharepoint 2010 template.